# Naming a page index.html changes it?

Tags: html, css, indexing

I restarted my laptop and it was fine.
Thankyou for the replies

The problem is, I have two pages and they have exactly the same code, the only difference are the file names, which is index and index2, but for some reason index header div is smaller than the index2 header div, even though there is no difference between them.

Comment: What header - the HTTP header?

Comment: The div element, 

Right I have two pages index and about, they are exactly the same, the coding is exactly the same, yet for some reason, the header div in about is bigger than index

Comment: The header div,
Right i have index and a about page, 
they are exactly the same coding, but for some reason, the index page header div is smaller than the about div, but if i rename index to a different name then it changes to the about header div size :S

Comment: Can you post the code of each?

Comment: Could you roll-back to the original question, please (albeit you can leave it closed, as it's solved), this is a q&a website, to help others in future as well as yourself. Removing the question isn't useful.

Answer (score 3):

This is a caching issue, probably.

Try clearing your browser cache and then reloading the page with CTRL-F5 or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is anything like this! There must be some problem with the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a line break in the source can cause this, or even an extra space. Can you post the code so we can look at it? That would help immensely.